# Input voltage swing when starting a DC brushed motor

Tags: microcontroller, power-electronics, dc-motor, brushed-dc-motor

I am working on a circuit that include a H-bridge for a DC brushed motor. I am having problem when the system might run for a short period of time (5s) before the Micro-controller stop responding. I am suspecting that the noise from the motor is causing the corruption on I2C line or brownout due to voltage swing. Further inspection, I can see that the swing in the 12V rail is shown in all 3V and 5V rails. I don't know why and how would I isolate this swing to just the 12V rail or reduce the swing peak-peak?

System description:

- Single GND, all power from a 12V battery that can handle 10A peak
- 12V ->5V buck regulator (47uF output cap) to step down voltage for micro-controller **board** Vin
- 5V-> 3.3V (unsure value of output cap) linear regulator for uC IC
- 470uF bulk cap + 0.1uF ceramic cap next to H-bridge driver, there is 3 more 470uF caps at further distance
- Low power DC motor (1A at normal operation, ~3.6A starting)
- H-bridge control is just on/off, no PWM
  [image: Motor set up]

GND of Oscilloscope is at common GND point (where the battery is plugged in)

When measuring the voltage at the leg of the H-bridge capacitor, motor turn on give make the 12V voltage swing above and below 12V.
Voltage across the 12V cap
[image: Voltage across the 12V cap]

Voltage at 3.3V linear output
[image: Voltage at 3.3V linear output]

Voltage at 5V buck output
[image: Voltage at 5V buck output]

Comment: You have a very bad buck converters. First you have to eliminate the cap on the motor, or add additional series chokes on connection wires.

Comment: That possibly suggests poor earthing practice. Use the 12V battery -ve (or a short fat cable from the H bridge to it) as a star earth point.

Comment: I have tried to change the GND to star config, as well as T-config like Andy, has suggested. Both don't work. So I tried to add diode at 5V input, doesn't work noise went through 5V and 3.3V. So I search around and add x2 0.1uF caps between motor terminals to the case, noise on the 12V drop from 10% pk-pk, to 1%pk-pk. This makes the noise fall below my scope trigger for 5V and 3.3V. All sensor and uC work as expected now!

Comment: Running the motor for 3 hours to reshape the brushes also help a lot with the noise.

Answer (score 1):

Try "holding up" the voltage input to your buck regulator using this method and see if it improves things: -

[image]

Also try putting 1 kohm resistors in series with the control lines feeding the H bridge.

You should also ensure that the only connection to your battery negative terminal goes directly to the H-bridge 0 volt connection. The rest of your control circuit and regulators tee-off their ground from the H-bridge 0 volt connection that the battery feeds. This avoids ground bounce.

Comment: I have tried but only the diode changes the peak-peak a bit. Turn out adding a 0.1uF cap between the motor case and motor terminal works the best. Thank you